# Spring TokenBasedRememberMeServices with hashed password

Tags: java, security, spring-security, token

I am using [StandardPasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) which hashes the password using SHA-256 with 1024 iterations and 8-byte salt. I was looking at [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html) for doing a similar thing or at least using it but there is a problem with the salt. According to the documentation, the token consists of the following:

> username + ":" + expiryTime + ":" + Md5Hex(username + ":" + expiryTime + ":" + password + ":" + key)

But the problem is that the Md5Hex part will differ because of salt, and there is no way to separate it IMO. Does TokenBasedRememberMeServices work with salted passwords? If not, how would you recommend doing an alternative token?
Is there any way to do it without using a persistent store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the issue, it turned out that there is no way to use salted passwords with tokens and therefore had to send a normal password.